# Loading string from plist swift

Tags: swift, plist

I am trying to load a string from plist with the code below, then i want to use it in typewriter animation. But I failed to convert the string into the array. How should I convert it?
The line var myText = Array(Data[0].characters) gives error.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var Data = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let word = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Chapter 1", ofType: "plist")
        let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: word!)

        Data = dict!.objectForKey("Chapter 1") as! [String]

    }

@IBOutlet weak var myTypeWriter: UILabel!



    var myText = Array(Data[0].characters)
    var myCounter = 0
    var timer:NSTimer?

    func fireTimer(){
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.typeLetter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    func typeLetter(){
        if myCounter < myText.count {
            myTypeWriter.text = myTypeWriter.text! + String(myText[myCounter])
            let randomInterval = Double((arc4random_uniform(8)+1))/100
            timer?.invalidate()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(randomInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.typeLetter), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        } else {
            timer?.invalidate()
        }
        myCounter += 1
    }
```

Comment: What error? Please add that to your Q.

Comment: You are trying to use Data before being initialized, from your code, you expect to do it in viewDidLoad(). 
Would be better if you define myText as a String or Array

Comment: I tried define myText like that var myText = String()
    myText = Array(Data[0].characters) But still error

Comment: Wow, so many forced stuff in your code... no wonder you get runtime errors. First, get rid of the forced unwraps by replacing them with optional binding, after this you'll be able to better debug your code and find out the cause of the problems. Secondly, you are accessing `Data[0]`, but are you sure that `Data` has at least one element?